# there are caused deadlock condition and advise me how to fix and i need general advises

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

i learn java multithreading. there are caused deadlock condition and advise me how to fix and i need general advises.
i understood what does means deadlock concept but it can resolve problem on one.
here is code:

java Util class:

```
// in multithreading. 
class Util 
{ 
    // Util class to sleep a thread 
    static void sleep(long millis) 
    { 
        try
        { 
            Thread.sleep(millis); 
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

java Shared class:

```
// This class is shared by both threads 
class Shared 
{ 
    // first synchronized method 
    synchronized void test1(Shared s2) 
    { 
        System.out.println("test1-begin"); 
        Util.sleep(1000); 

        // taking object lock of s2 enters 
        // into test2 method 
        s2.test2(this); 
        System.out.println("test1-end"); 
    } 

    // second synchronized method 
    synchronized void test2(Shared s1) 
    { 
        System.out.println("test2-begin"); 
        Util.sleep(1000); 

        // taking object lock of s1 enters 
        // into test1 method 
        s1.test1(this); 
        System.out.println("test2-end"); 
    } 
}
```

java Thread1 class:

```
class Thread1 extends Thread 
{ 
    private Shared s1; 
    private Shared s2; 

    // constructor to initialize fields 
    public Thread1(Shared s1, Shared s2) 
    { 
        this.s1 = s1; 
        this.s2 = s2; 
    } 

    // run method to start a thread 
    @Override
    public void run() 
    { 
        // taking object lock of s1 enters 
        // into test1 method 
        s1.test1(s2); 
    } 
}
```

java Thread2 class:

```
class Thread2 extends Thread 
{ 
    private Shared s1; 
    private Shared s2; 

    // constructor to initialize fields 
    public Thread2(Shared s1, Shared s2) 
    { 
        this.s1 = s1; 
        this.s2 = s2; 
    } 

    // run method to start a thread 
    @Override
    public void run() 
    { 
        // taking object lock of s2 
        // enters into test2 method 
        s2.test2(s1); 
    } 
}
```

And finaly GFC class for main method:

```
public class GFG 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // creating one object 
        Shared s1 = new Shared(); 

        // creating second object 
        Shared s2 = new Shared(); 

        // creating first thread and starting it 
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1(s1, s2); 
        t1.start(); 

        // creating second thread and starting it 
        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2(s1, s2); 
        t2.start(); 

        // sleeping main thread 
        Util.sleep(2000); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes, but how fix it based on this example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you provided does indeed cause a deadlock. Initially, `t1` obtains the intrinsic lock for `s1` and `t2` obtains the lock for `s2`. Then `t1` tries to obtain the `s2` lock while still holding the `s1` lock. Since the `s2` lock is held by `t2`, `t1` will block waiting for the lock to be released. A similar situation happens with `t2`: it tries obtain the `s1` lock while still holding the `s2` lock. Since the `s1` lock is held by `t1`, `t2` will also block. This leads to a deadlock.

To fix this, both threads should use only one lock for synchronizing their work. A possible solution is:

```
class Shared
{
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    // first synchronized method
    void test1(Shared s2)
    {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            System.out.println("test1-begin");
            Util.sleep(1000);

            // taking object lock of s2 enters
            // into test2 method
            s2.test2(this);
            System.out.println("test1-end");
        }
    }

    // second synchronized method
    void test2(Shared s1)
    {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            System.out.println("test2-begin");
            Util.sleep(1000);

            // taking object lock of s1 enters
            // into test1 method
            s1.test1(this);
            System.out.println("test2-end");
        }
    }
}
```

This will fix the deadlock. However, considering the current implementation, it will lead to an infinite loop caused by indirect recursion: `s1.test1(s2)` -> `s2.test2(s1)` -> `s1.test1(s2)` -> `s2.test2(s1)` -> ...